# extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, extension-field

Suppose that $K$ is a field, $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq K$ and $[K:\mathbb Q]=n$. If there is
$$\Phi:K\to M_2(\mathbb{Q})$$
a ring homomorphim, what are the possible values of $n$?

Comment: What have you tried? You must at least be able to rule out or confirm some numbers. Can we have $n=1\,000\,000$? Can we have $n=1$?

Answer (score 3):

If $K=\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, then $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $\Phi(\alpha)$.
So $\alpha$ has degree $\le 2$ over $\Bbb Q$ and therefore $n\le2$.

Comment: I would think it more immediate to point out that the minimal or the characteristic polynomial of $\Phi(\alpha)$, which by injectivity must also have $\alpha$ as a root, has degree at most $2$. Also, are you certain that such a short answer really helps the OP?